# apply changes to other files via git?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have a git repo with lots of quite similar files (something like config files).
It often happens that I have to do a certain change to all of those files (change a parameter value or add a new parameter).
Does anyone know a way of doing this change to only one of the files and then "cherry pick" it to the other files with git?
I understand that git has the capability of doing this if the files are each in it's own git repo and all have the same name - so I was wondering if there is a (possibly scriptable) way of using this capability for files that have different names but are in the same repo...

Comment: see if `diff` and `patch` utility can help (they are not part of git though)

Comment: im not sure if git would help you with this topic